# USB internet not accessible

Tags: mobile-broadband

I'm brand new to ubuntu and linux. We access internet from a usb stick issued by a local telephone company. When I plug the stick into the computer, I see the device listed under internet connections as a mobile broadband device but it is grayed out and inaccessible.

I tried to create a new mobile broadband connection but my country (Gabon) is not listed and we have no payment plans per se (we pay from a pre-paid card system)..

Any clues as to how I can get the system to recognize the internet connection?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0):

you have a option here . If your country not listed then you have option for that also . I mean look this

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The only thing here matters is APN of your Network , no matter how you pay . 
Hope that helps .

Comment: From what the user said the option is grayed out and inaccessible. So he may not be able to do that

Comment: If there is no connection created then it will grayed out .

Comment: I also have an USB internet stick and that's not what happens. The option is not grayed out or inaccessible.